# Mirroring part of a molecule

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

Does anyone have an idea how can I mirror a part of a molecule like in the picture?
Thanks!
Roland

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\decoRule}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

%\definesubmol{Abase}{\chembelow{N}{H}*5(-=N-*6(-(-NH_2)=N-=N-)=_-)}
%\chemfig{[:72]!{Abase}} %%%%adenine alone

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%in RNA
\definesubmol{CRbase}{*6(-N-(=O)-N=(-NH_2)-=)}

\definesubmol{aR}{-P(=[::90,0.75]O)(-[::-90,0.75]O)-}

\definesubmol{ARbase}{[:-54]*5((-[:90]-[:180]O([:180]!{aR}\charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O}))<(-HO)-[,,,,line width=4pt](-OH)>((-[:90]N*5(-=N-*6(-(-NH_2)=N-=N-)=-)))-O-)}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\chemfig{!{ARbase}}
```

EDIT:
What I was looking for was a command like `\hflipnext` but only affecting one part of the molecule.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{*6((-OH)--=-(-OH)--)}
    \arrow
    \hflipnext
    \chemfig{*6((-OH)--=-(-OH)--)} 
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\newcommand{\decoRule}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}

\begin{document}
\definesubmol{CRbase}{*6(-N-(=O)-N=(-NH_2)-=)}

\definesubmol{aR}{-P(=[::90,0.75]O)(-[::-90,0.75]O)-}

\definesubmol{ARbase}{
  [:-54]*5(
  (-[:90]-[:180]O([:180]!{aR}
  \charge{135:3pt=$\scriptstyle\ominus$}{O}))<(-HO)-[,,,,line width=4pt](-OH)>
  (
  (-[:90]N
  *5(-
  *6(-N=-N=(-[,,,1]NH_2)-
  )
  =-N=
  --
  )
  )
  )-O-
  )
}

\chemfig{!{ARbase}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as far I can see you just re-coded the part of the molecule that I wanted to be mirrored. I have more than one of such molecules so re-coding everything was what I wanted to avoid. See my Edit.

Comment: @Roland, the new version is a different and much more difficult question than your original one.

Comment: That is why it was unanswered for so long I guess. It is now just a clearer version. Sorry, I thought it was clear that re-wrtiting code is not an option, since nobody asked for details.

Comment: @Roload, no problem. Good luck!!